# I find this error: Illuminate\Routing\Exceptions\UrlGenerationException Missing required parameters for [Route: Product.update]

Tags: laravel

Controller:

```
public function update(Request $request, Product $product)
{
    $request->validate(['name'=>'required',
        'price'=>'required'
    ]);
    $product->update($request->all());
}
```

In the view:

```
<form action="{{route('Product.update',$product)}}" method="GET">
```

Route:

```
Route::resource('Product', 'ProductController');
```

Parameter Request will come from the data of form

Comment: Welcome to SO ... what is `$product` in your view?

Comment: in view index i have a loop for print all products from database and in this view there is <a href="{{route('Product.edit',$item)}}" knowing that item is the variable of foreach loop

Comment: not the index, the view you are showing the form from ... what is `$product`

Comment: is the variable passing to view edit  : return view('Product.edit',['product'=>$product]);

Comment: and what is that variable?

Comment: it is the parametre of edit function the product that we want to edit

Comment: okay and does it have a value? can you just show the code how you get that

Comment: there is the index view  that shows all products : name, price and some action like edit link : <a href="{{route('Product.edit',$item)}}" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a>

Comment: item is a variable of foreach loop

Comment: How does your `Product.php` model look like? My problem was because of `getRouteKeyName` when a model record was null

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
<form action="{{route('Product.update',$product)}}" method="GET">
```

to

```
<form action="{{ route('Product.update', ['product' => $product]) }}" method="POST">
```

Comment: thanks for the help but still giving me the same error

Answer (score 0):

The default Route::resource HTTP method for update action is 'patch' and 'put'.
So in view, you may pass 'post' as method instead of 'GET'.

Then you should write {{ method_field('PUT') }} and a hidden input after your form tag as below :

```
<form method="POST" action={{ route('product.update' , $product) }}>
           @csrf
           {{ method_field('PUT') }}
           <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

Looking through the Laravel docs, I think for the view you need to do POST instead of GET. You might also need to spoof the form method with `@method('PUT')`.

Comment: thanks for the help but still giving me the same error